# How to get the average of the text file values and output it in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, average

I have this GUI project where I have to get the values of a file, get the average of the values by clicking a button and output the result to a JTextArea. What my code does is it gets the value of the text file and output it in a JTextArea `textbox1`. My problem is getting the average. I use `.getText()` to get the value of the text file that was outputted on `textbox1` then I split the values since the values are separated by `;`, then I get the average. Problem is, my code only add the individual values and do not divide by the number of elements, therefore only printing the added value of each of the numbers. Can anyone give some advice on what to do?

Note that I get the average by clicking a button and have to output the result in a JTextArea called `textbox2`.

Here's my code

```
btn4.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            Double num,ave = 0.000000000, sum = 0.0000000;
            String input = textbox1.getText();
            String[] inputed = input.split("[ ;]+");
            int length = inputed.length;
        
            for(String part: input.split("[ ;]+"))  {
                for(int i=0; i < length; i++) {
                    num = Double.parseDouble(part);
                    sum += num ;
                }   
            }       
                ave = sum / length ;
                textbox2.setText(" " +ave);             
        }
        });
```

Here are the contents of the text file:

```
5.12345;1.1;2.12;3.123;4.1234;
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the text file, given that is apparently not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Streams API to get the average in a single statement as shown below:

```
double average = Stream.of(input.split(";")).collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::parseDouble)).doubleValue();
```

Modify your `widgetSelected()` method as shown below:

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    String input = textbox1.getText();
    double ave = Stream.of(input.split(";")).collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::parseDouble)).doubleValue();
    textbox2.setText(" " +ave);             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the resul is wrong because the nested for statement:
for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
shouldn't be there since it sum any number in input string length times

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    String input = "1; 2; 3; 100";

    int length = 0;
    for(String part: input.split("[ ;]+"))  {
      sum += Double.parseDouble(part);
      length++;
    }     
    double ave = sum / length ;
    System.out.println(ave);
  }
}
```